# Is there way to make visual studio not to take string literals as pointer to constant?

Tags: c++

Is there way to make visual studio not to take string literals as pointer to constant? because in my university we are using visual studio 2013 which take these string literals as pointers not pointer to constant. That's why I have difficulty to work with different rules;

Comment: What would be the purpose of doing that? The C++ standard defines that string literals are immutable, so why do you want a non-`const` pointer?

Comment: Could you provide an example in code? You mention Visual Studio, but it has nothing to do with the code being executed.

Comment: string literals have the type `const char[N]`.  That means they decay to a `const char *`.  This  is required by the language.  You'll need to change your code t handle that.  If you need a modifiable string, use a `std::string`.

Comment: Any context you're passing a string-literal should by-definition be utilizing a pointer to const char, (const reference to array of char deductions and conversion constructions to `std::string` notwithstanding), so if you have code that declares `char *` and *allows* passing a literal, its bad code, a bad compiler for allowing it, and honestly, *both*.

Answer (score 2):

You can make behavior consistent and correct in both cases by using [`/Zc:strictStrings` compiler option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-strictstrings-disable-string-literal-type-conversion?view=msvc-160).